# Swift 1.2 NSDate?! is not convertible to NSDate

Tags: swift

After upgrading to 1.2, I have the compile error:

```
NSDate?! is not convertible to NSDate
```

Code:

```
let dateCreated = photoCommentObjects[indexPath.row].createdAt as NSDate
```

#### Other attempt:

I also tried:

```
let dateCreated = photoCommentObjects[indexPath.row].createdAt as? NSDate
```

I get error:

```
Downcast from NSDate?! to 'NSDate' only unwraps optionals
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `photoCommentObjects[indexPath.row].createdAt` is returning a type of `NSDate?!` which is an implicitly wrapped optional of an optional.  To unwrap that, first cast the result to `NSDate?` with `as` to remove the implicitly wrapped optional, and then use optional binding to unwrap the resulting `NSDate?`:

```
if let dateCreated = photoCommentObjects[indexPath.row].createdAt as NSDate? {
    // use dateCreated which is of type NSDate
}
```

The result is that `dateCreated` will be a plain `NSDate`.

---

Alternatively, you can use:

```
if let temp = photoCommentObjects[indexPath.row].createdAt, dateCreated = temp {
    // each assignment unwraps one layer of Optional
    // use dateCreated which is of type NSDate
} else {
    println("something is nil")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a type problem. You have an array with `AnyObject` type and you cannot read a property on `AnyObject`.

```
//sample data
class PhotoComment {
   let createdAt = NSDate()
}

let photoCommentObjects: [AnyObject] = [PhotoComment()]
```

```
//let's get the indexed object first and let's cast it from AnyObject
let photoComment = photoCommentObjects[indexPath.row] as! PhotoComment
//now trivially
let dateCreated = photoComment.createdAt
```

or

```
//let's cast the whole array first
let photoComments = photoCommentObjects as! [PhotoComment]
let dateCreated = photoComments[indexPath.row].createdAt
```

Comment: getting error `could not find member 'createdAt'` This used to compile with no problems.

Comment: could you add the declaration of `photoCommentObjects`? What type is  it? What is the type of `createdAt`?

Comment: `photoCommentObjects` is type `[AnyObject]`

Comment: I have made a mess of the answer - writing about dictionaries when you are using an array. I can't reproduce your error but it is probably a type problem when trying to access a property on `AnyObject`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried?

```
let dateCreated = photoCommentObjects[indexPath.row].createdAt as! NSDate
```

Since Sift 1.2 you have to explicitly mark forced casting with `!`.
This as a reminder for you that if it fails, your app will crash.